# Expand all the items of an NSOutlineView to a level

Tags: macos, cocoa-touch, nsoutlineview

How can I, on setup, expand all items of an NSOutlineVIew to a determined level? After this the user it's free to expando or collapse all the nodes of the tree.

The data comes from a NSTreeController bound to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < outlineView.numberOfRows; i++)
{
    if ([outlineView levelForRow:i] < depthLimit)
        [outlineView expandItem:[outlineView itemAtRow:i]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was already planning to do to something like that. The cocoa APIs are still rather new to me.